# What's the difference between a maisonneuve fracture and a Weber C fracture?

Tags: orthopedics, ankle, bone-fractures, sprain-strain-twist, fibula

I feel like they're the same thing. Sprained syndesmotic ligaments, sprained deltoid and fractured fibula. So why is the maisonneuve fracture its own thing?

Answer (score 1):

The **Maisonneuve fracture is a special form of the Weber C fracture**. What makes it special is that the fracture of the fibula has to be localized within the **proximal third of the fibula shaft** (see "The Maisonneuve fracture is a spiral fracture of the proximal third of the fibula", http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23079149). **Weber C includes all localizations** of the fracture of the fibula.